# Using Postman to test KOHA RestAPI but keep getting authentication failure

Tags: oauth-2.0, basic-authentication, postman-testcase

I have a problem working with Postman and Koha RestAPI to display desired input.

I want to try GET request on Postman using this URL as endpoint: https://{KOHADomain}/api/v1/patrons?userid={userid}.

What supposed to happen is the output should display all patrons detail in json or xml, but I keep getting this message:

```
{
    "error": "Authentication failure."
}
```

The url works fine in the browser after login using KOHA privilege account. It displays all the desired output in xml form, but not in Postman.

The methods that I have tried:

1. Clear browser's cache.
2. Re-login Koha account.
3. Use Basic Auth.
4. Use OAuth 2.0. (client_id, secret_key, Token Access URL)

I really appreciate if someone could help me find the solution for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue (well, i used basic auth). Restarting the apache server after enabling the auth method helped. Use

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```